# How does Two parts conjunctions relate to one part Conjunctions?

Tags: conjunction

So I know there are two type of single part conjunction, subordinating and coordinating. Seeing guide on the internet gives me an impression that two part conjunctions are replacements for [coordinating conjunction](https://www.deutschesinstitut.it/doppelkonjunktionen/), so would it be correct to think that they both equivalent for conveying **literal** meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Herr Antrim video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNUX6TFkjfM) gives a variety of two-part conjunctions. I think the issue is more complex than you're making it, since many two-part conjunctions have their own quirks and subtleties that make generalizations difficult. In most cases, two-part conjunctions are coordinating with a single part alternative, but some are not. For example with "*je ... desto*", the clause following "*je*" is verb final, so it appears to be a subordinating conjunction. On the other hand, you can also change the clause order with a subordinating conjunction, but you can't put "*desto*" before "*je*", making it more like a coordinating conjunction. It appears then that this lies in some middle category. Also, "*je ... desto*" does not have any single part alternative, literal or otherwise.